# Is there an interchangeable definition of additional editor highlights?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, webstorm

I am looking for a way to define additional keywords for comment highlighting in my editor, like `todo:` or `fixme:` and I would like to define them for the whole project to share them with my colleagues, so that everybody's editor highlights the same keywords without the need to define them manually in every editor. 
(We mainly use WebStorm and VSCode)

Is there an interchangeable definition file that can be read by the major editors to achieve something like that?

Comment: you can check editor-config spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: editor>TODO>edit pattern]

you can export your preferences from perferences tab and then it can be imported by anyone using the project

Comment: Thank you. It seems that exporting -> importing is the best way possible, though it is not the most convenient one.